# Group by date, Distinct and ignore other filters - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the dataset where the values in the col 'value' are repeated per month and id, e.g. for 1/1/2020 and id 1, the value is 0.5, for 2/1/2020, the value is 2, etc. The dataset has other columns which are to be used as filters for other calculations.

[image]

What will be the measure to get:

[image]

so that even when I use filters from the table, e.g. filter1, the value remains grouped by date ONLY?

I've tried with sumx and max; sum and value but nothing gives a result and calculation still reacts on other filters.

Comment: You can remove filter context from some column in your calculation by using FILTER(); Read about ALL for eg. ALLEXCEPT:

ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[date] ) -> this will remove all filter from all column expect filter on date column

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/

Comment: @msta42a, in my case, I don't need a simple sum of 'value', it will be sum of distinct value per id, which in turn summed up by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i spoke abount ALL i had in mind this kind of solution:

```
WithoutExternalFilter =
CALCULATE (
    VAR __dist =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( Te, Te[Date], Te[ID] ),
            "val", CALCULATE ( MAX ( Te[value] ) )
        )
    RETURN
        SUMX ( __dist, [val] ),
    ALL ( Te[filter1] )
)
```

[image]

WHEN we put some filter, value for "2020-08-01" is still 1.1:

[image]